# How to surround an overlayed (z-indexed) image with a surrounding ring of transparency?

Tags: css, image, z-index, transparency

I am trying to create image icons that have a status dot which emulates Slack member-icons (left).

**How can I use CSS to add a transparent ring around the dot?**

[image]

```
.memberIconRow {
    display: flex;
    .memberIconArea {
        position: relative;
        img {
            width: 30px;
            margin: 0 6px 0 0;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        .statusDot {
            background: #f00;
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 2;
            top: 21px;
            left: 23px;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some dirty trick what I think of is add border to your dot with the same background as your photo, in this case - a light yellow.

Like this -

```
.statusDot {
    ...
    border:4px solid yellow; /* same color as you profile photo background */
}
```

In multiple background colours case, use css var() like;

```
:root {
  --blue: #1e90ff;
}
.member-bg { 
    background-color: var(--blue);
}
. statusDot { 
    border: 4px solid var(--blue); 
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought of that, but in this case, the background can have various colors. I'm trying out `border: 4px solid transparent` and `border: 4px solid transparentize` but can't get it.

Comment: "Transparent" will make you still see through the below photo unless cover it with solid color or so. What about using css var()? Example: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_var